# Which kingdom is the fourth kingdom in Daniel 2?

Tags: catholicism, daniel, rome

I’m interested in the Christian viewpoint on Daniel 2? Which kingdom is the fourth kingdom represented by the iron legs of the image? Do Christians believe this is the Romans?

I am assuming, correct me if I am wrong, that Christians believe that the stone cut but not by hands which destroys the kingdom is the anointed king of Israel. Given that Rome has long been under the control of Christians does this mean that Christians believe that the Messiah will come to destroy Christianity in general or just Catholicism?

Comment: Given that there are bound to be diverging opinions about this, could you please reformulate the question in a way that makes sense.  There's a gigantic catch-22 in your premise which makes the question impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, there are two Christian viewpoints as to what the iron legs refer to, depending on whether one holds that the destruction of the statue occurs in the end times of the world, or whether it has already happened when Jesus Christ died for sinners and rose from the dead.

Those who hold the statue was hit and began to collapse happened at the cross of Christ and his resurrection believe the iron empire is the Roman Empire.  This is the view I personally hold.  This view is given some support by Daniel 9:24-27 where the "seventy sevens", if taken as 490 years, from the time of the Persian Empire points to the Messiah coming during the days of the Roman Empire, *nomatter which theory of those possible one takes for the start date*. (My prefered option is the start date of 458 bc for the seventh year of Artaxerxes/Ahasuerus in Ezra 7:9.)

Those who hold the statue's fall happens in the end time hold that all the  empires and human institutions since the time of the Roman Empire are included in the legs of iron.

Neither view would see the Messiah as coming to destroy Christianity, though the second view may hold the dream is intended to include the destruction of false versions of Christianity in the great Day of Judgement.

The real focus of the dream and its interpretation is, *on the one hand*, man's rebellion against God, the fleeting nature of man's success, the illusory nature of man's pomp and power, the vicious cruelty of man's kingdoms, the force and violence used to impose these kingdoms against the will of those subjugated, and *on the other hand* the eternal nature of God's Kingdom which in all these characteristics will be radically different/opposite from the kingdoms of men, and which in particular, men will be happy to enter of their own free choice. The Kingdom of God will start here on earth.

Interestingly, the idea of four ages, the Golden Age, the Silver Age, the Bronze Age and the Iron Age is a theme with which the educated in Babylon could have been already familiar when Nebuchadnezzar had his dream.  It had already been used by the Greek poet Hesiod about 200 years before Daniel, and some modern scholars believe the idea was not original to Hesiod, that he had taken the idea from some other writer(s).

Hesiod had an extra age, the Heroic Age, between the Bronze Age and before the Iron Age.  The chief difference between the interpretation of Daniel and the writing of Hesiod, in his work called "Works and Days", is that Hesiod is looking *back* through human history to the first age, the Golden Age of paradise when men lived long, there was perfect peace and harmony, and no hard work, and the Iron Age was the one Hesiod was living in, hard and cruel; but in Daniel's interpretation Daniel is looking *forward*, so that Nebuchadnezzar and Daniel were themselves living in the Golden Age and the remaining ages were in their future.

And of course, the other difference is that, in the book of Daniel, Man's ages will finally come to an end in God's timing when He brings in the Eternal Age of the Kingdom of God.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151974/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-shanks-which-kingdom-is-the-fourth-kingdom-in-dan); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.